# Save files in special folder

Tags: ios

I created application (Swift 4.2), 1st user sends URLs to 2nd user:

```
http://www.website.com/test1.zip
http://www.website.com/test2.exe
http://www.website.com/test3.png
http://www.website.com/test4.mkv
```

Second user should download and save files in folder at his device.

- How can I download files and save them in "Files" folder?
- Can I create "MyApplication" folder automatically and save files
  inside this folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is a Document-Based App. In this case, you must add and set `UISupportsDocumentBrowser` key to `YES` in your Info.plist file, then ALL your folders and files in your App Document Folder will be exposed here. When you open Files app, your App's documents will be at On My iPhone -> YOUR_APPLICATION_NAME

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

First Question:

- You can download them on your pc and then transmit them to your iPad with  apps like `iFiles`, which can be installed from Appstore.

Second Question:

- To download files directly and save in your own folder is not permitted on iPad for the intentional restrict of Apple.

Comment: No, I created application (Swift 4.2), 1st user sends URLs to 2nd user. Second user should download and save files in folder at his device. Is it possible?